# How to add button in the same line as text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, alignment

I want to add a button to the right of some text. Both the text were added using JS DOM. I researched a lot, but couldn't place it there. It always goes to the next line. How do I do this?

```js
var text = document.createElement("h4");
var content = document.createTextNode("Insert buttton here:--> ");
text.appendChild(content);

document.body.appendChild(text);


var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.textContent = "Place me right of the -->";

document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 29px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the button to an inner html of `h4`.

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.textContent = "Place me right of the -->";
var text = document.createElement("h4");
text.innerHTML = "Insert buttton here:-->" + btn.outerHTML;

document.body.appendChild(text);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 29px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append the button to the `h4` ?

```js
var text = document.createElement("h4");
var content = document.createTextNode("Insert buttton here:--> ");
text.appendChild(content);

var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.textContent = "Place me right of the -->";

text.appendChild(btn);

document.body.appendChild(text);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 29px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```